# Z3 Python multiply two bitvectors

Tags: z3, z3py

I am trying to do some calculation using `Python` + `Z3` bitvectors, and I am having some problems for the `multiply` operations.

For example:

```
a = BitVecVal(3, 2)
b = BitVecVal(3, 2)
c = a * b
print c.size()   <----- output is 2; but can I have a vector of length 2 + 2 = 4??

print simplify(c)  <---- of course, the output is 1, not 9
```

The example above should be very clear. I would really appreciate if anyone can educate me **how to do multiply on bitvectors without cutting some highest bits.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to extend the length of the bit-vectors before multiplying:

```
  from z3 import *

  a = BitVecVal(3, 2)
  b = BitVecVal(3, 2)
  c = ZeroExt(2, a) * ZeroExt(2, b)
  print c.size()

  print simplify(c)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Nikolaj!